# Networking local device with external server

Tags: networking, share

I have local networking between my embedded device and PC via Ethernet wire. I set static IP address on my embedded device (10.171.88.2) and static IP address for my PC (10.171.88.1) as well. I can connect PC & embedded device locally.

I have external Linux server which I am connected via VPN over my WiFi and it's on different network.

Now I'd like to have connection between ext. server (Wifi/VPN to my PC) and local embedded device (connected to PC locally with Ethernet wire). 
How should I set the network to have communication between server & embedded device?

I want to have scp and now I have "no route" between the local embedded device and the external server.

Comment: Routers route between different networks, and bridges switch between devices on the same network. If all the devices are on the same network, you will bridge on the common device. If they are on different networks, you will need to set up routing. The end-devices will need to be told that they must go through the common device to get to the other network, and the common device must be set up to route between the networks.

Comment: Your explanation seems reasonable ... So devices are not on the same network. I need to set routing - how should I do that on my windows PC machine?

Comment: You should ask that question on [su]. The site is for application development, but [su] covers this sort of question.